# Select Distinct without sorting

Tags: sql, ms-access, distinct

I used a Select Distinct query, which resulted me a sorted data. Is there anyway that i dont get data sorted?

Comment: I'm just curious to know why it makes a difference whether it is sorted or not. If you needed it in a certain order then you could sort it accordingly but if you don't, why is the fact that it is sorted an issue?

Comment: Pretend it isn't sorted.  If you need it randomized, that's a different issue.

Comment: When you take away Distinct, is it still sorted?

Comment: could your data source possibly be giving you the data in that order? (Like if you called a sorted view or something similar)

Comment: "SELECT DISTINCT(ID) from Table_ABC"   ID is a number that may have different random values. The results of the query gives me a list of unique IDs starting from the lower to high. Whereas i want a list of unique IDs in the same order as present in the table.     Any suggestion how to do?

Comment: it must be database specific, i run a similar query against iSeries DB2 and get the results in the order entered in table.

Comment: It happens in Microsoft SQL Server 2008. I can also verify that the acutal execution plan shows a `Clustered Index Scan`, followed by a `Sort`, followed by a `Select`. I couldn't find anything about a guaranteed sorting in the documentation though.

Answer (score 10):

I'll try to elaborate a bit as to what's going on and why... though I agree with @vic's comment to the question...

- Without explicitly stating an order (via an `order by` clause) there is absolutely no guarantee of any order in the result set.
- Practically speaking, many queries will return a consistent order based on the query plan and how the data is actually stored and accessed... DO NOT RELY ON THIS!
- Specifically, for a `distinct` query, the sql engine will sort the data so that it can be sure to remove any duplicates.

In short, if the order of the result set matters (even if the desired order is "random") you must ALWAYS explicitly state it.  That said, from a purely set-based-math/sql standpoint, the order of the result shouldn't matter.

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter unless you're walking the resulting recordset and doing something procedural that is dependent on the order of the recordset. But, of course, in that case, you apply the desired ORDER BY. Nonetheless, my point is that the order *can* matter for a SELECT statement that is not being displayed to the user.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton, fair enough, I've edited the final sentence to be more specific, and less of a blanket "this is bad" comment.

Answer (score 2):

Put this at the end of your query. This will effectively randomize the results which then will appear to you non-sorted ;)

```
ORDER BY Rnd([ID]);
```

Replace the `ID` with primary key of the table. In Access SQL it is possible to call certain VB Functions directly. In this case the `Rnd` function can be called in a query and fed a seed value from the data being sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I think sorting may have something to do with the way DISTINCT is determined.
The easiest way to return distinct values is to sort the selection set 
returned by processing the SQL predicate and then
returning only the rows where the DISTINCT columns change value from the prior row.

In short, 
DISTINCT requires a sort to be performed where duplicate rows are dropped.

That said, there is no guarantee that rows are returned to you in any particular
order unless you explicitly include an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Also a hash algorithm may be used, in which case the rows may not be returned in sorted order.

Comment: Well, there's no guarantee in SQL theory, but Jet/ACE returns a DISTINCT query in the order of the fields in the SELECT statement (with default ASC order). In Jet/ACE, I don't know if adding an ORDER BY that is identical to the SELECT with result in extra processing or not (though that's not the question here, which is to have a sort that *isn't* identical to the ORDER BY of the fields in the SELECT statement).